# estimate how much RAM usage loading image dataset might use

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm working on the kaggle cat vs dog image classification challenge. My PC for now has only 8GB RAM, so with some of it used I have about 6GB to spare.

Started by trying to load the image test_set that's 12,500 images and it occupies 285 mbs on the hard disk. Running the script it uses up all available RAM and would likely just choke the PC to a halt so I stopped it before it went past 95% used.

```
import os

test_images = os.listdir('data/test')
print(len(test_images))
>>> 12500

test_images_data = []

for image in test_images:
    image_data = cv2.imread('data/test/' + image)

    #convert color from BGR to RGB
    image_data = cv2.cvtColor(image_data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    test_images.append(image_data)
```

Is there a way to tell how much RAM it's likely to use before hand so I know for example if adding 8GB more RAM will be enough?

Comment: So what is the dimension of the image.? The memory needed will depend on it too.

Comment: it varies, this is before any preprocessing to set them to equal dimensions but I'd say the maximum is 400 x 400 pixels in rgb.

Comment: For a rough estimate, use extrapolation. Measure RAM usage before loading images, load 1,250 images, measure RAM usage again, subtract the two and then ten times that.

Comment: @grooveplex thanks I'll try that.

Comment: you'll need at least width x height x channels x bitsPerChannel memory per uncompressed image (for 8 bit channels roughly 10x the size of a jpeg afair, but strongly depends on the content). If you use 32/64 bit floating point representations instead of 8 bit int, you'll need 4/8x the memory. If you use special techniques like deep neural network training you'll need much more memory compared to just holding the raw data.